# mongoose populate does not contain documents

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodes

I am trying to use populate(), however it seems like it doesn't contain transactions in user.

Is there something wrong in my code?
The transaction Table contains userId. Therefore, I thought it would automatically contains array of transactions that matches with the userId.

**User Table**

[image]

**Transaction Table**

[image]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: 
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        transactions: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Transaction'
        }
        ],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)



const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const transactionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        userId: 
        { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true 
        },
        payer: String,
        points: 
        { 
            type: Number, 
            reqruied: true 
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Transaction', transactionSchema)


exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    User
        .find()
        //.findOne({ _id: "6009f3d8019a22479cb21a5d"})
        .populate('Transaction')
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your User-Schema you've defined the transactions as `transactions`, so you need to populate it under this name:

```
User.find()
        .populate('transactions')
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        })
```

Comment: @Jake: any feedback?